# Append certain number of characters from a string to another string

Tags: c#, string

This is a pretty basic question, but here it goes: Is there a string method in C# that adds a number of characters from a string to another string? In C++ std::string class, there was the append method that had three parameters: source string, indexStart, offset.

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "bar";

a.append(b, 0, 2); // a is now "fooba";
```

In C# I also tried with StringBuilder, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable. Once a string is created, you can't modify it. However, you can create a new string by concatenation, and reassign it to the same variable:

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "bar";

a = a + b.Substring(0, 2); // a is now "fooba";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "bar";

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(a);
sb.append(b.SubString(0,2));

string res = sb.ToString(); // res = "fooba"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're feeling adventurous, you could also write an extension method:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static string Append(this string original, string textToAdd, int length)
    {
        if (length <= 0)
        {
            return original;
        }

        var len = (textToAdd.Length < length)
                      ? textToAdd.Length
                      : length;

        return original + textToAdd.Substring(0, len);
    }
}
```

Then to use it you would go like this:

```
string a = "foo".Append("bar", 2);
```

or

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "bar";
string c = a.Append(b, 2);
```

This also has the nice advantage of allowing error/exception handling in a central location.

Comment: Now, that's really sweet! Thanks! :)

Comment: Definitely a nice feature of c#.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
 string aa = "foo";
            string bb = "bad";
            bb= string.Concat(aa, bb.Substring(0, 2));
```